# Adding a loading gif to an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've looked at several answers for this, [the most informative of which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765568/adding-a-loading-gif-to-simple-script) says "show it as soon as you start the AJAX request", and then "hide the image again once the request has been completed". How would I do that? Is it like:

```
showGif();
$.ajax({
    url: whatever,
    success: function(data) {
        hideGif();
    }
});
```

Or is there a better way of doing it? What if the ajax request doesn't succeed?

Comment: This is how you should go. You can also put it in `complete` so it fires whether it's a success callback or an error callback.

Comment: @JohnP Ah, that may be what I need. Does `complete` trigger when the request is done, no matter what happens?

Comment: Yes it does. Just keep in mind that it triggers after the `success` and `error` callbacks. I don't know whether the order is important to you, but generally it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to style the loading gif into the page using conventional HTML and CSS, but by default I set it to hidden. You can then use an AJAX event handler to hide and show your loading gif without repeating any code:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   $("#loading").show();
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
   $("#loading").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend running this on `always` so that it is hidden whether the request is successful or fails:

```
showGif();
$.ajax({
    url: whatever,
    success: function(data) {
        //
    }
}).always(function(){
     hideGif();
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between `$.always` and `complete`?

Comment: `complete` is deprecated. `always` is the new preferred method. `Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem if you do `hideGif();` in ajax `success`. But i suggest you to do it into ajax [`complete`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

**Ajax complete: A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed).**

```
   showGif();
    $.ajax({
        url: whatever,
        success: function(data) {
           //-- Do your other stuff here
        },
        complete: function () {
          hideGif();
       } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there a better way of doing it?

I don't think so.

> What if the ajax request doesn't succeed?

You could extend this method to display an error message when an error occurs.

```
showGif();
$.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    // success
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // error
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    hideGif();
  });
```